# Are images guaranteed to have at least 1 width and 1 height?

Tags: javascript, html

When we load an image and it's `onload` handler runs, is it guaranteed that the width and height is at least one?

```
var img = new Image();  
img.onload = function(){
    // is img.width and img.height guaranteed to be at least 1?
    // can we do something like assert img.width >= 1 && img.height >= 1
};
img.onerror = function(){
    alert("error");
}
img.src = 'MyImage.png';
```

Basically, I was wondering is it even possible for a *loaded* image to have a width or height of 0?

Or rather, is there even an image extension (gif, png, svg, jpg, exif, raw, bmp, tiff, etc) that supports 0 width or 0 height images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a single raster image encoding format that supports image widths of zero. SVG might be able to, or perhaps another vector format, but no raster format would.

Answer (score 0):

Whats the point of an image with width=0px ?
Then you should not put the image there at all.
So yeah, the min-width of an image is 1px

But when you set the width in %, it's possible to set

```
<img src="...." alt="image" width="0%" />
```

then the image is not visible

Comment: It's not so much that I wanted a 0-width image, it's more of can we do *assert img.width >= 1 && img.height >= 1*

Comment: When i set the width of an image of my website to width="0px" it's just showed as the full resolution of the image. The only way to give it a 0 value is to set is as %, then when you say width="0%" the image is not visible

Comment: I mean that I do not explicitly set a width to the image, so that when the image is loaded, it automatically assumes the width and height of the original image as depicted in it's img.src. So my question is when we do not explicitly set the image's dimension, is it possible that after loading an image the width and/or height will be zero?

Comment: Don't think so, if you don't give any width or height to the image, it will set itself to the normal resolution of the image. It will always be visible and never have default width or height of 0px.

Answer (score 0):

Good question but as I understand it no you can't have an image file with 0 x 0 pixel dimensions.

With CSS you could

- hide it
- make it 1x1 pixels
- position it absolutely etc so it doesn't affect your UI layout.

Comment: Is it possible to create a 0x0 image using .exif, .raw, or .svg?

Comment: I doubt it, none of the imaging tools I've used allows less than 1 pixel. Programmatically speaking it might be possible. `var img = new Image();` has 0 width and 0 height...